# Деструктор и указатель на объект

Tags: c++, деструктор

Например, есть у нас класс Klass, в нем есть конструктор и деструктор:

```
class Klass{
public:
    Klass(){cout<<"Konstructor";}
    ~Klass(){cout<<"Destructor";}
};

int main(){
    Klass klass1;
    Klass *klass2=new Klass();
}
```

Вывод:

```
KonstructorKonstructorDestructor
```

Почему простой объект вызвал деструктор, а указатель на объект - нет?

Comment: "Деструкторы" в С++ есть только у объектов типа "класс". А указатели - скалярные объекты. У указателей нет деструкторов. Да даже если бы они и были, что по вашему они должны были бы делать? Что именно вы предлагаете "удалять" в деструкторе указателя?

Comment: Не ответ, но `new/delete` не стоит использовать без крайней необходимости. Все-таки 2018 год на дворе, у нас давно есть контейнеры и умные указатели...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо за совет. До этого не знал о умных указателях, буду теперь практиковать :)

Answer (score 1):

У указателей тривиальные деструкторы по историческим причинам. Сделать деструктор указателя не тривиальным и удалять в нем объект, на который указывает указатель не возможно по следующим причинам:

- указатель не обязательно владеет объектом, на который указывает

```cpp
{
    int val{};
    int * p_val{&val};
} // автоматический вызов delete p_val вызвал бы UB
```

- даже если указатель владеет объектом, на который он указывает, то этот объект может быть создан каким угодно способом, а не только с помощью `new`

```cpp
{
    int * p_val{static_cast<int *>(::std::malloc(sizeof(int)))};
} // автоматический вызов delete p_val вызвал бы UB
```

Comment: то есть, можно удалять только через delete .. ; ?

Comment: @RoarRaizZer Удалять нужно способом, обратным способу создания объекта. При помощи `delete` можно удалять только объекты, созданные при помощи `new`.

Comment: @RoarRaizZer, указатель может указывать не только на динамический объект, но и на стековый объект или на статическую переменную. Причем в разное время один и тот же указатель может указывать на разные объекты, выделенные разными способами.

Answer (score 1):

Сам указатель и объект, на который указатель указывает - это совершенно отдельные, независимые, самостоятельные сущности. Даже если бы у указателя и был деструктор, он бы все равно не имел никакого отношения к деструктору указуемого объекта.

Указатель в общем случае не имеет ни малейшего представления о том, когда и кем должен быть уничтожен указуемый объект. Например, на один и тот же объект могут указывать 100 указателей. Эти 100 указателей ничего друг о друге не знают. Если один из этих указателей заканчивает свое существование и вместе с собой вдруг вздумает уничтожить и указуемый объект, то куда после этого будут указывать остальные 99 указателей?

Например, пользуясь объявлениями из вашего примера

```
int main()
{
   Klass *ptr1 = new Klass;

   {
     Klass *ptr2 = ptr1;   
   } 

   delete ptr1;
}
```

Когда заканчивается время жизни указателя `ptr2`, откуда он может знать, нужно ли ему уничтожать указуемый объект? Знать этого он не может никак.

Comment: Если во втором предложении допустить "умный и владеющий" указатель, то он так и работает.

Answer (score 0):

вы создали обьект в динамической области памяти. Деструктор вызовется только после вашей команды:

```
 delete klass2;
```